# Use regex in IDL to escape special character in directory name

Tags: regex, idl

I am trying to run a model on a cluster but IDL is throwing an error when using openw because the file locations name has [] in it (this is my conclusion after some testing).  What I'd like to do is
feed IDL a slightly different string that includes escape characters. I believe one way to do this is with regex but I could use some help and specifically don't know much IDL.

```
temp_dir='/local/scratch/1940320[2000].cluster.name/temp/area'
openw,12,temp_dir+'file.dat'
```

How would I send:

```
temp_dir2='/local/scratch/1940320\[2000\].cluster.name/temp/area'
openw,12,temp_dir2+'file.dat'
```

The number represents the jobid on the cluster, and I don't know this until its running.  /local/scratch/$PBS_JOBID.cluster.name is held in $TMPDIR which I'm getting with `getenv('TMPDIR')`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's a bit awkward, but this should work:

```
IDL> temp_dir = '/local/scratch/1940320[2000].cluster.name/temp/area'
IDL> temp_dir = mg_streplace(temp_dir, '(\[|\])', '\\$1', /global)
IDL> print, temp_dir
/local/scratch/1940320\\[2000\\].cluster.name/temp/area
IDL> temp_dir = mg_streplace(temp_dir, '\\\\', '\', /global)
IDL> print, temp_dir
/local/scratch/1940320\[2000\].cluster.name/temp/area
```

`MG_STREPLACE` is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib/blob/master/src/strings/mg_streplace.pro).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found another way that I posted as well.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague wrote this for me:

```
IDL> spawn,'printenv TMPDIR | sed "s/\[/\\\[/" | sed "s/\]/\\\]/"',mytemp
```